# drf-spectacular define request content type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, content-type, x-www-form-urlencoded, drf-spectacular

In drf-spectacular swagger, post method have 3 content types as below

```
application/json
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

Is there anyway to make "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**" as default content type for my post method.

```
@extend_schema(
    description='API authentication using email & password',
    # OpenApiRequestBody('content': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
)
```

In extend_schema function, tried to add content type as form-urlencoded. but no luck.

Thanks in advance